# see if the node exists in Jackrabbit AbstractWebDavServlet in JackRabbit

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr, content-repository, sardine

I am working with a jackrabbit server where we faced a problem on running multiple Repositories in a cluster.
The problem is that the Folder structure path for a file insertion happens sometimes on the 1st repo and the insertion of the file on the 2nd(before both the servers get synced up).
The solution i designed for this is to change the Jackrabbit source code and CREATE A FOLDER PATH FOR A FILE IF THE FOLDER PATH DOSENT EXIST instead of just throwing back a 409 CONFLICT error
Following is the change in AbstractWebDavServlet in JackRabbit web-Dav

```
    protected void doPut(WebdavRequest request, WebdavResponse response,
                     DavResource resource) throws IOException, DavException {

    DavResource parentResource = resource.getCollection();
    if (parentResource == null || !parentResource.exists()) {
        if(!parentResource.exists()) {
            try {
                createFolder((Session)request.getSession(), parentResource.getLocator().getPrefix(),parentResource.getLocator().getHref(true));
            }catch(Exception e) {
                throw new IOException();
            }

        }
        // parent does not exist
        response.sendError(DavServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT);
        return;
    }

    int status;
    // test if resource already exists
    if (resource.exists()) {
        status = DavServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT;
    } else {
        status = DavServletResponse.SC_CREATED;
    }

    parentResource.addMember(resource, getInputContext(request, request.getInputStream()));
    response.setStatus(status);
}
private String[] getFolders(String desUrl) throws Exception {
    if (null == desUrl || desUrl.length() == 0)
        return null;

    String[] folder = desUrl.split("/");
    String[] folders = new String[folder.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < folder.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            folders[i] = folder[i];
        else
            folders[i] = folders[i - 1] + "/" + folder[i];
    }
    return folders;
}

public void createFolder(Session session123,String prefix,String href) throws Exception {
    String[] folders = /*this.getFolders(href.substring(prefix.length(),href.length()))*/href.substring(prefix.length()+1,href.length()-1).split("/");
    if (null != folders) {
        String davFolder = "";
        int length = folders.length;
        //Session session123 = ((JcrDavSession)session).getRepositorySession();
        Node rootNode=session123.getRootNode();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(!rootNode.hasNode(folders[i]))
                IOUtil.mkDirs(rootNode, folders[i], NodeType.NT_UNSTRUCTURED);
            else
                rootNode.getNode(folders[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

..

Now im in a nightmare situation trying to figure out a way to get the session.The above method for getting the jcr session dosent work.

PLEASE PLEASE HELP

Comment: Can't you just use rootNode.getSession()?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use the same technique as `doMkCol()` does:

```
parentResource.addMember(resource, getInputContext(request, null));
```